# How to remove the first and last comma after an equal sign with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following string :

```
WORKSPACES="workspace1,workspace2,workspace3,workspace4"
```

In a loop, I remove some workspaces and the result is the following :

```
WORKSPACES=",workspace2,workspace3,"
```

Or the below one (it depends of the workspaces removed) :

```
WORKSPACES="workspace1,,workspace3,"
```

I tried this code, but it's not working :

```
sed -i "s/\<,$WORKSPACE,\>//g" file
```

Or :

```
sed -i "s/\,<$WORKSPACE\>,//g" file
```

For now, the code to remove a workspace name in my loop is the following :

```
for WORKSPACE in "${workspaces[@]}"; do
    sed -i "s/\<$WORKSPACE\>//g" file
done
```

I would like to have a result without a comma if it's the first and/or last character after the equal occurrence and have only one comma between each workspace value like the following (for example) :

```
WORKSPACES="workspace2,workspace4"
```

The content of my file is:

```
    export WORKSPACES="workspace1,workspace2,workspace3,workspace4"
```

Comment: I feel like removing a workspace might be better done with other means than `sed`. Can you provide some sample lines of your input file?

Comment: so you want to edit a shell script?

Comment: If you remove the first and the last comma, your first example string would become `WORKSPACES="workspace1workspace2,workspace3workspace4"`. Please specify the outcome for the general case, for instance `FOO,BAR=,BAZ,,,,` - how should this be transformed?

Comment: I have my deletions done, and end up with a string of type (for example): 
export WORKSPACES=",workspace2,,workspace4" 
And I would like the result to be: 
export WORKSPACES="workspace2,workspace4"

Answer (score 1):

You are painting yourself into a corner with the commas. You can't require a comma on both sides, so you need to perform multiple replacements, or refactor your regex.

Some `sed` implementations will allow you to say

```
sed -i 's/\(^\|,\)workspace1\(,\|$\)/,/;s/^,\|,$//g'
```

If you can't do that, you need a more complex script;

```
sed -i 's/^workspace1/,//;s/,workspace1,/,/;s/,workspace1$//'
```

Keep in mind that `sed` is a scripting language, so you can perform all the replacements in a single invocation. Repeatedly running `sed -i` in a loop is an antipattern you want to avoid.

If your `sed` accepts a script on standard input, try

```
for workspace in "${workspaces[@]}"; do
  echo "s/\"$workspace,/\"/;s/,$workspace,/,/;s/,$workspace\"/\"/"
done |
sed -i -f - file
```

If not, you can generate the script in a Bash array with some additional tedium, and then run `sed -i "${scriptarray[@]}" file`

Comment: None of the examples above work. I have my deletions done, and end up with a string of type (for example):
    export WORKSPACES=",workspace2,,workspace4"
And I would like the result to be:
    export WORKSPACES="workspace2,workspace4"

Comment: My initial attempt assumed you were looking to replace at beginning or end of line. Updated to adapt to replacing within a double-quoted string.

Comment: My goal is to remove the extra commas, in order to have my values separated by a single comma and not to have any at the beginning or at the end between my double quotes after the equal sign

Comment: All tested now; demo: https://ideone.com/AfeoNg

Comment: The above script works fine finally :
for workspace in "${workspaces[@]}"; do
  echo "s/\"$workspace,/\"/;s/,$workspace,/,/;s/,$workspace\"/\"/"
done |
sed -i -f - file

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this in a single `sed` command. You need to construct a  regex pattern from your shell array using `IFS`, then use that pattern in `sed`.

```bash
# content of the shell array
workspaces=(workspace1 workspace4)
# sed command
sed -E "s/$(IFS='|'; echo "(${workspaces[*]})")(,|(\"))/\3/g; s/,\"/\"/" file
export WORKSPACES="workspace2,workspace3"

# more examples
workspaces=(workspace2 workspace3)
sed -E "s/$(IFS='|'; echo "(${workspaces[*]})")(,|(\"))/\3/g; s/,\"/\"/" file
export WORKSPACES="workspace1,workspace4"

workspaces=(workspace1 workspace3)
sed -E "s/$(IFS='|'; echo "(${workspaces[*]})")(,|(\"))/\3/g; s/,\"/\"/" file
export WORKSPACES="workspace2,workspace4"
```

If you want to save changes inline the use `-i` option in `sed`.

[<kbd>Working Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/n9zKhp)

Note that this is the shell command we are using to construct a regex pattern using *alternation*:

```bash
workspaces=(workspace1 workspace3)
echo $(IFS='|'; echo "(${workspaces[*]})")

(workspace1|workspace3)
```

Comment: my entrie is WORKSPACES="workspace1,workspace2,workspace3,workspace4", with the above examples, I'm facing the below erreor :
sed: -e expression #1, char 86: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Make sure you are using `bash`. I have tested it before posting.

Comment: I tried but my entrie is not workspaces=(workspace1 workspace3) but WORKSPACES="workspace1,workspace2,workspace3,workspace4"

Comment: `workspaces=(workspace1 workspace3)` is not the line in the file. It is your **shell array** that you are looping through in the sample code in question.

Comment: I have included an online working demo for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It sounds as if you are determined to work in a particular format. Some reason you can't use arrays?

```
$: IFS=, read -a ws <<< "workspace1,workspace2,workspace3,workspace4"
$: new=( ${ws[@]//*[24]/} )
$: ( IFS=,; echo "${new[*]}" )
workspace1,workspace3
```

Kludgy chicanery there, though -
c.f. the [parameter expansion rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [use of IFS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS).

Simpler and more readable to just push your result string through a simple `sed` scrubber. Does this not accomplish what you wanted?

```
$: printf "%s\n" ",workspace2,workspace3," "workspace1,,workspace3," |
    sed 's/^,,*//; s/,,*$//; s/,,*/,/g' # or sed -E 's/^,+//; s/,+$//; s/,+/,/g'
workspace2,workspace3
workspace1,workspace3
```

Without seeing more of your code, though, I'm concerned all these suggestions will just complicate more what might have been a much simpler operation in a larger context.